# MonthCalender to textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use MonthCalender to insert date in text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852496/how-to-use-monthcalender-to-insert-date-in-text-box)

I have `textBox1` and `MonthCalender1` How I can make the selected date in the calender mapped as a string in `textBox1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in selected change event of calender :

```
protected void MonthCalender1 _SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.DateTime myDate = MonthCalender1 .SelectedDate;

    textBox1.Text = myDate.ToString ("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
}
```

Comment: calender has selected date property.visit msdn link below :    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddates.aspx

Comment: Shoot, I was looking at the `MonthCalendar` for some strange reason.

Comment: @WajidAli :  `System::DateTime^ myDate = monthCalendar1->SelectedDate;` Shows error: `Error 3 error C2039: 'SelectedDate' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::MonthCalendar' c:\users\40612010\desktop\hrnimr2\hrnimr\Form1.h 1819
`